# How to add Sequelize Association into Model

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am new to Typescript and trying to connect with the Mysql database I have created the following files

#### User.ts

```
export const UserData = sequelize.define('users', {
id: {
    type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement:true,
    allowNull:false,
    primaryKey:true
},
 name: {
    type:Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull:false
},
address: {
    type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull:false
}
});
```

#### Address.ts

```
export const CityData = sequelize.define('city_data', {
id: {
    type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement:true,
    allowNull:false,
    primaryKey:true
},
city: {
    type:Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull:false
},
house_no: {
    type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull:false
}});
```

here I want to add hasMany association on User model user hasMany => address[] How can I achieve that?
what I am looking here how to use sequelize in typescript how to create setup and save data into tables ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users.hasMany(city_data, {
  foreignKey: "address",
});
```

Or

```
UserData.hasMany(CityData, {
  foreignKey: "address",
});
```

#### how to add :

```
const UserData = sequelize.define('users', {
id: {
    type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement:true,
    allowNull:false,
    primaryKey:true
},
 name: {
    type:Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull:false
},
address: {
    type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull:false
}
});

UserData.hasMany(city_data, {
  foreignKey: "address",
});

export UserData;
```

Comment: do I need to add this before export?  or just add into city_data object like other properties?